# php utf8_encode - chars get prepended with \u

Tags: php, unicode, utf-8

I've got an ISO string that I fetch from database, and when I utf8_encode it, I get a \u00f6 instead of Ö. This confuses the javascript/html which ajaxes this PHP script. Why is there a \u00f6 instead of Ö? How to get Ö instead?

edit:
Ok, I did some more experimenting and it turns out this is caused by combination of utf8_encode and json_encode. Though if I don't utf8_encode at all, the value will be null in the json.

```
json_encode(array("city"=>utf8_encode("göteborg")))
```

Comment: Paste your php code from your ajax-page that does the conversion and printing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`utf8_encode` doesn't encode characters to `\uxxxx`, as you figured out yourself it's `json_encode` doing this. And that's fine, because the JSON format specifies this behavior. If your client properly decodes the JSON string into a Javascript data type, the `\uxxxx` escapes will be turned into proper Unicode characters.

As for `json_encode` discarding characters if your string is Latin1 encoded: It's not explicitly stated on the manual page, but Javascript and JSON are entirely Unicode based, so I suspect Latin1 is an invalid and unexpected encoding to use with JSON strings, so it breaks.

Answer (score 1):

How do you print that? javascript natively support \uXXXX encoding, and doing this in javascript:

```
var x = "\u00f6"; alert(x);
```

should print out a small ö.

EDIT: According to your code, if you output that directly to the response stream and use the actual response as a variable in js on the client side, you shouldn't care about json_encode at all.

You would just tell the browser that the content is utf8 by setting the content-type header:

```
header('content-type: text/plain;charset=utf8');
```

And then the jQuery.data() code would work just fine.

Comment: I set a jQuery.data(value) of input to it, and then I fetch that data and put it in an element. I get the \u00f6 directly in the html. The weird thing is that if I do utf8_encode("$lots of $variables") in the PHP, I don't get the \uxxxx, but if I do utf8_encode($variable), I do get \uxxxx.

Comment: is value the actual response of your XHR-request? I guess that the output generated (however I don't think it's utf8_encode that does it) is ment to be outputted into js-code, meaning json-serialization or equivalent. Hence, if you just want to take the output and put in a variable it shouldn't be encoded.

Comment: +1. If you check on http://json.org/, you'll see, that `\u00f6` is valid JSON representing `ö`. Plus it has the added benefit to keep your JSON response strictly in the ASCII set.

Comment: I updated my answer to perhaps reflect what you are trying to achieve, but since you don't tell us how you fetch the data and how you expect it to be sent, it's only a guess.